# javascript: How to check if a link is clicked over context menu new tab

Tags: javascript, browser

Is it posible to check if a link is clicked to open up in a new window?
I mean ctrl or shift key pressing is clear, you can handle this events, but what about the right click context menu in the browser? Here you can click the context menu item open in another window..

Jquery context() method triggers when the context menu is opened:

```
$("a").contextmenu(function() {
  alert("context");
});

$("a").click(
    if (evnt.ctrlKey || evnt.shiftKey || evnt.metaKey || 
        (evnt.button && evnt.button == 1)){
        alert("link clicked");
    }
);
```

Comment: Show us research/code/examples you have done prior to asking this questions. Refer to: [`How do I ask a good question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Have a look here too: [`.contextmenu()`](https://api.jquery.com/contextmenu/) which `jQuery` supplies.

Comment: Thanks, I have already seen the contextmenu()  method, but this triggers only on menu open. I would like to get the action of the open in new tab menu item.

Comment: Not possible, and also rather none of your business :-)

Comment: @CBrone would you be kind enough to explain to OP why it's not possible instead of just stating it.

Comment: @Franki1986 you can make your own context menu using [`jQuery contextMenu`](https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html). This will give you control over the events of each context menu item. [`Plugin Github Link`](https://github.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this solution, it's very hacky and DIY but should do the trick.

The trick is to create your own context menu using this `jQuery` plugin:

> `https://rawgit.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu/master/dist/jquery.contextMenu.js`
>   `https://rawgit.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu/master/dist/jquery.contextMenu.css`
>   `https://rawgit.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu/master/dist/jquery.ui.position.js`

This doesn't execute on `SO` and I recommend running it on JSFiddle: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/trkj25oq/26/)

---

```js
$(function() {
  $.contextMenu({
    selector: '.context-menu-one',
    callback: function(key, options) {

      var m = "clicked: " + key;
      window.console && console.log(m);

      switch (key) {
        case "open_new_window":
          console.log($(this));
          //var win = window.open($(this)[0].href, '_blank');
          window.open($(this)[0].href,'_blank');
          //win.focus();
          break;
        case "cut":
          break;
      }
    },
    items: {
      "open_new_window": {
        name: "Open link in new tab",
        icon: "edit"
      },
      "cut": {
        name: "Cut",
        icon: "cut"
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu/master/dist/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu/master/dist/jquery.contextMenu.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu/master/dist/jquery.contextMenu.js"></script>


<a class="context-menu-one" href="https://www.google.com">Google</a><br>
<a class="context-menu-one" href="https://www.bing.com">Bing</a><br>
<a class="context-menu-one" href="https://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a><br>
<a class="context-menu-one" href="https://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a><br>
```